# screen rotation fix with ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX on TrekStor SurfTab W1

Tags: 22.04, systemd, udev, sensors, display-rotation

Hi askUbuntu community

I recently managed to install Ubuntu 22.04 on a TrekStor Surftab W1 10.1, and I have problems with the screen rotation.

With research, I figured out that I need to adapt the ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX by adding to `/etc/udev/hwdb.d` the file `61-sensor-local.hwdb`

here is my output of `udevadm info -n /dev/iio\:device1`

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:02/i2c-2/i2c-BMA250E:00/iio:device1
N: iio:device1
L: 0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/808622C1:02/i2c-2/i2c-BMA250E:00/iio:device1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/iio:device1
E: DEVTYPE=iio_device
E: MAJOR=235
E: MINOR=1
E: SUBSYSTEM=iio
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=14257714
E: IIO_SENSOR_PROXY_TYPE=iio-poll-accel iio-buffer-accel
E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=iio-sensor-proxy.service
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:
```

and `dmidecode BMA250E | grep Product`

```
    Product Name: SurfTab duo W1 10.1 (VT4) 
    Product Name: Cherry Trail CR
```

and `dmidecode BMA250E | grep Manufacturer`

```
    Manufacturer: TrekStor
    Manufacturer: Hampoo
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Manufacturer: Hynix Semiconductor
    Manufacturer: Hynix Semiconductor
    Manufacturer: Intel
```

with these results put this in `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-sensor-local.hwdb`

```
sensor:modalias:acpi:BMA250E*:dmi:*:svnTrekStor*:SurfTabduoW110.1(VT4):*
 ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=-1, 0, 0; 0, -1, 0; 0, 0, -1
```

I updated hwdb with `systemd-hwdb update` and `udevadm trigger`.

I tested different values for the matrix and the behavior kept the same.

What did I do wrong?

Regards JoniG59